# Mysql character encoding fail

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I have a large table (~17k rows) in a mysql database. Some of the fields in the table should contain the swedish characters "åäö", but right now it contains characters like "Ã¤" instead of "ä". How can I fix all my data so the characters will be correct? The character set of the table is already utf-8, and if I update a field in the table manually I am able to enter åäö.

How can I fix all fields (wont be able to do it manually since it is ~17k rows)?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: Try `iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", $field)`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php